# How to set 2 POST methods for one servics in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to set 2 different POST methods for one service like this:

```
angular.module('admin').factory('Cards', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return {
      admin:
        $resource('api/admin/cards/:cardId', {
          cardId: '@_id'
        }, {
          update: {
            method: 'PUT'
           }
        }),
      user:
        $resource('api/user/cards/:cardUserId', {
          cardUserId: '@id'
        }, {
          add: {
            method: 'POST'
           }
        })
    };
  }
]);
```

Part of server routes:

```
  app.post('/api/get/cards', card.add);
```

And I'm trying to access it:

```
card.user.$add()
card.user.add()
card.add()
card.$add()
```

And nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

Your route in express does not match that of either resources, in other words '/api/get/cards' !== 'api/admin/cards'.

If you log the request url in express, it should be easy to find the mismatches. Something like console.log(req.originalUrl).

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Really it's 
app.post('/api/user/cards', card.add);
But it still not working...